# Vaadin flow: format number when focus leaves

Tags: migration, vaadin, vaadin-flow

We are using TextField as number input field in our application. Because TextField  value is a string, we added various converters to the TextField. For example,

```
TextField textFieldNetWeight = new TextField()
BindingBuilder<?, ?> bb = binder.forField(textFieldNetWeight );
((BindingBuilder<?, String>)bb).withConverter(new StringToBigDecimalConverter("Failed to convert"));
```

setBean and getBean are used for binding. When a user enters net weight, and focus leaves the field, the field shows formatted number (thousands separated number) in V8, but not in V14. We know the converter is correct, because when data is saved and shown again, the data is formatted.

What can I do to make it show formatted number when focus leaves the field?

For various reason, writeBean and readBean cannot be used here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you are referring to is only  default  active in 8.12+ and 19+.

You need to use `setConvertBackToPresentation(true)` on your bindings in 14.x to enable this behavior.